# SQL SUM and comparing

Tags: mysql, sum

I have two database tables:

```
***aff_purchases***

id | affiliate_id | payout
1  | 12           | 50.00 
2  | 12           | 10.00
3  | 12           | 50.00
4  | 12           | 10.00

***aff_payments***

id | affiliate_id | amount_paid   
8  | 12           | 50.00
```

I would like to return an array of all affiliate IDs where the 'payout' total is 50 or more than the 'amount_paid' for an affiliate ID.

I think that I need to SUM together the columns and then compare, but I am struggling to understand how. Please see my efforts below:

```
SELECT
     (SELECT SUM(amount_paid) FROM exp_cdwd_aff_payments AS pay WHERE pay.affiliate_id = 12) AS 'amount_paid'
     (SELECT SUM(payout) FROM exp_cdwd_aff_purchases AS pur WHERE pur.affiliate_id = 12) AS 'payout'
FROM 
     exp_cdwd_aff_payments AS pay
WHERE 
     payout > amount_paid
```

Comment: What do you want returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach here is to use join two separate subqueries which find the payout and payment totals.  Then, compare each `affiliate_id` to see if meets your requirement.

```
SELECT
    t1.affiliate_id
FROM
(
    SELECT affiliate_id, SUM(amount_paid) AS amount_paid_total
    FROM aff_payments
    GROUP BY affiliate_id
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT affiliate_id, SUM(payout) AS payout_total
    FROM aff_purchases
    GROUP BY affiliate_id
) t2
    ON t1.affiliate_id = t2.affiliate_id
WHERE COALESCE(t2.payout_total, 0) > t1.amount_paid_total + 50
```

Note that affiliates who have a payout, but have not paid, would not appear in the result set.

Comment: Thanks Tim. 
Regarding your comment, do you mean if an affiliate has an 'amount paid' total, but no 'payout' total the result would be omitted?

Comment: No, I am saying that if an affiliate _only_ appears in the paid table, but not the payout table, then he would not appear in the result set.  If you give more info about your data, I can adjust my query.

Comment: Thats fine Tim. I only want to return affiliate IDs where the 'payout' total is 50 more, so if there is no 'payout' total, they need to be omitted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot use aliases defined in the `SELECT` in the `WHERE`.  In most databases, you would use a CTE or subquery.  However, MySQL does not support CTEs and it imposes overhead on subqueries (by materializing them).

So, MySQL has overloaded the `HAVING` clause, to allow it to be used in non-aggregation queries.  You can do what you want using `HAVING`:

```
SELECT a.affiliate_id,
       (SELECT SUM(cap.amount_paid) FROM exp_cdwd_aff_payments cap WHERE cap.affiliate_id = a.affiliate_id) AS amount_paid
       (SELECT SUM(pur.payout) FROM exp_cdwd_aff_purchases pur WHERE pur.affiliate_id = a.affiliate_id) AS payout
FROM affiliates a
HAVING payout > amount_paid;
```

The above assumes you have a table with one row per `affiliate_id`.  It uses this via a correlated subquery.  Also note the use of table aliases and qualified column names.

Comment: I don't see an `affiliates` table defined/mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . There should be one if a column is called `affiliate_id`.